Does Hashset<IDisposable> prevent or extend the dispose of the Idisposable members?
In dotnet, if I create a (HashSet<T> disposable) where T : IDisposable and store the hashSet object in a field. When the Disposable objects will be disposed? Consider this code:
    public class LongRunningProcess: ServiceBase 
    {
        private HashSet<IDisposable> set;

        public LongRunningProcess()
        {
            set = new HashSet<IDisposable>();
        }
        void Process()
        {
            using (var disposable= new IDisposable() )
            {
                if (!set.Contains(disposable))
                    //Process
                else
                    set.Add(disposable);
            }
        }
    }

In this code I have created a class that holds onto the HashSet field, because it is a worker service it never dies (until next restart). Does that imply that the hashset's members will be disposed of at restart? Considering that hashsets are a set of hashes does their lifespan affects the lifespan of their member object?

Each item will be disposed when the using block exits.

You can also find this out by implementing a basic IDisposable and checking when its Dispose gets called. It doesn’t really have anything to do with HashSet.

You seem to be mistaken as to how IDisposable works. You MUST explicitly dispose all disposables. The Garbage Collector does NOT do it for you.

In other words, nothing gets disposed at reset unless you explicitly do so.

The small caveat here is that a disposable may also implement a finalizer that may call .Dispose() that may run when garbage collected. You would need to look at the source code for all of your disposables to know if this may happen.

@John Wu Does that mean the hashset field would contain nulls after the using statemen? I thought the hashset field postpones the disposal of its members because it lives longer than them.

@Enigmativity Here in the Process() I have disposed the IDisposable but the hashset lives longer untill the next restart.

The reference of the object is not related to if it is disposed or not. The hashset will hold references to disposed object (they won't become nulls). How those objects behave in their disposed state is implementation specific. There is nothing stopping you from continuing to use disposed objects, although it wouldn't be recommended.

@Hamed - If they're disposed then there is no point, whatsoever, in keeping the references.


When the Disposable objects will be disposed?

When the using block exits:
void Process()
{
     using (var disposable= new IDisposable() )
     {
          if (!set.Contains(disposable))
              //Process
          else
             set.Add(disposable);
     } // <--- disposable is disposed here
}

But disposing an object does not affect its lifetime as far as Garbage collection is concerned. The hashset will keep a reference to the object, preventing it from being collected. So your example would likely be a memory leak. At least unless most objects are equal to some previous object.
It is not clear from the example what the intent is. But you probably do not want to hold on to a bunch of disposed objects. So either remove the hashset, or remove the using, make the entire class IDisposable, and dispose of all the objects in your dispose method. Just make sure to also dispose objects that where not added to the hashset due to a preexisting object. You may also want to add some error handling code to ensure objects are correctly disposed if the processing fails.
If your disposable object owns any native resources it should have a finalizer that releases the resource when the object is collected, unless Dispose was already called. But this is not always done by third party libraries, and GC is not determistic, so this should not be relied upon.
Also note that set.Add returns a bool to tell you if the object was added, so you could probably just write
if (set.Add(disposable)) // Process


All the answers above are correct but I did not understand them until I read this SO thread.
Which explains how disposing and destructing an object are two different things. While a using statement disposes the resources, Hashset would refer to the object until it is destructed (finalized).

The HashSet would prevent the objects from being destroyed. And I don't know why you want to do that.
